# Como capturar cada tecla pressionada em uma Entry com tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, eventos

Utilizando a biblioteca *tkinter*, eu gostaria de realizar uma pesquisa no banco de dados a cada tecla apertada pelo usuário numa Entry, para que o resultado seja mostrado num Listbox automaticamente conforme vou digitando. Como posso fazê-lo ?

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisa criar um evento usando `Entry.bind()` chamado `"<Any-KeyPress>"` passando a função que deseja chamar. Dessa forma, sempre que o usuário apertar qualquer tecla, tendo a Entry foco, a função será chamada. Veja esse exemplo que eu criei abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *

def checkDatabase(event = None):
    root.after(100, lambda: print("Procurando por", entry.get()))

root = Tk()
Label(root, text = "Digite abaixo o que procura").pack()

entry = Entry(root)
entry.bind("<Any-KeyPress>", checkDatabase)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Uma coisa bem interessante que podemos observar nesse exemplo acima, é que dentro da função `checkDatabase`, eu estou utilizando o método `after()`. Eu utilizei esse método, para que a função não seja executada antes do caractere ser inserido no Entry, já que o evento é detectado antes.

Comment: ah ta então eu posso colocar nessa função para pesquisar o que to querendo no banco de dados em tempo real , entendi obrigado vou tentar fazer